# Do Artificers, Archivists, and similar classes have any way to exploit the transmuter's Spell Versatility?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, optimization, wizard, class

From [Unearthed Arcana](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/specialistWizardVariants.htm), specialist transmuters can gain the following:

> **Spell Versatility (Ex**)
>
> A 5th-level transmuter using this variant can adapt magic of other schools to his own style of spellcasting. For every five class levels that the transmuter gains, he can select one spell of any spell level that he has access to and treat it as if it were a transmutation spell. This means, for example, that the specialist can learn the spell normally and even prepare it as a bonus spell from the transmutation school. This spell can even be from a school that he has chosen as a prohibited school. Once a spell is chosen to be affected by this ability, it cannot be changed.

The example text describes this as a convenient way for a transmuter to obtain spells from schools that they have prohibited and I have little doubt that it's handy for giving spells some boosts from whatever bonuses to transmutation that you happen to have. However, **does this ability have any use for classes that are not Wizards, but can obtain their spells?** For example, I struggle to imagine that there's not some sort of Artificer, Archivists, Spell-to-Power Erudite, or even Advanced Learning exploit for this. Are there any tricks this can lead to this ability giving a class that really shouldn't have a certain spell access to said spell?

Note: Although it may be relevant and answers related to it would be accepted, this isn't intended as a question about multi-classing. My interest is mostly in what the optimization consequences of say, having a non-enchantment version of *Charm Person* existing or being able to make or access such a modified spell in scroll form.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That changes everything. If the spell never actually becomes a Transmutation spell, then I can't see any use for it for non-Wizards. If there is still a use then I'd be interested to see it, but if you're right then I suspect that my question is worthless.

Comment: @HeyICanChan You kinda answered the question, shouldn't you write an answer instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only if the artificer, archivist, or whatever *is* the transmuter, which is probably not what you had in mind—and not much of an “exploit.”

The issue is that spell versatility doesn’t change the spell—it changes the transmuter. It allows the transmuter to treat the spell as a transmutation, it does not make the spell actually into a transmutation. That means the transmuter can treat the spell as a transmutation wherever its source—say a scroll penned by a sorcerer, perhaps—but it makes it impossible for the transmuter to share that benefit—e.g. by scribing their own scroll. So another wizard copying the spell from their spellbook would treat it as its original school, as would an artificer using a wand they made.

However, the benefit applies to any spell the transmuter had access to and chooses—even if it’s not a wizard spell, and they only have access to it because they are multiclassed and get it from some other spellcasting class like archivist. Even artificer infusions are probably eligible, though that’s much less sure, since they claim to behave like spells in all ways aside from their specific limitations. But a minimum five levels in transmuter is pretty bad for any other spellcaster, so this “exploit” is really rather negative for them.